# Unable to reliably update Edittext hint from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I've got a fragment called "describer" that manages the description of a video by tags. I've got another called "Chat" that is an edittext allowing the user to chat. when the box is empty a placeholder (a Hint) remains. The hint will usually consist of the video's tags.

Whenever the user changes a video's description with new or different tags, the placeholder should update the Hint.

However in my case 2/3 times the placeholder does not update. And I have 0 idea what is causing the inconsistency.

Basically the code is split into 3.

This is the describer fragment method (the Fragment is a DialogFragment) which will pass back the new tag info to the parent activity via a listener:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.describe_done_button:
                if (mListener != null) {
                    HashMap<String, String> streemDescription = setStreemInfoToActivity();
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(streemDescription);
                }
                dismiss();
                break;
            default: break;
        }

    }
```

This is the activity listener. As you can see it both "listens" to the describer and calls the other fragment's activity to update the Hint:

```
  @Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(HashMap<String, String> streemDescription) {
    mStreem.setTitle(streemDescription.get(getString(R.string.title_constant)));
    for (int i = 0; i < mStreem.getTags().length; i++){
        String key = "tag"+(i+1);
        String tag = streemDescription.get(key);
        if (tag != null){
            if (tag.equals("")) tag = null;
            mStreem.setTag(tag, i);
        }
    }
    storeStreemInfo();
    TwitterChatFragment twitterChatFragment = (TwitterChatFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TWITTERCHAT_TAG);
    Log.i("IS FRAGMENT VISIBLE", String.valueOf(twitterChatFragment.isVisible()));
    if (twitterChatFragment != null){
        twitterChatFragment.setPlaceHolder(mStreem.getTitle(), mStreem.getTags());
    }


}
```

And finally the method in the Chat Fragment which is supposed to update:

```
 public String setPlaceHolder(String streemTitle, String[] streemTags) {
    String placeholder = "";
    placeholder += "I'm streeming live!";
    if (streemTags != null){
        for (String tag : streemTags){
            if (tag != null && !tag.equals("")){
                placeholder += " #" + tag;
            }
        }
    }

      if(!placeholder.equals("")) {
          mTweetCompose.setHint(placeholder);
          mTweetCompose.setText(placeholder);
      }


    Log.i("PLACEHOLDER", String.valueOf(mTweetCompose.getId()));
    return placeholder;
}
```

Some diagnoses I tried:

- are the string values being passed: YES.
- is mTweetCompose null: NO.
- is the setPlaceHolder method called on the UI Thread : YES.
- have you tried runonUIThread: YES for each of these methods, from describe
  fragment to activity to chat fragment.
- is the Chat Fragment visible: YES
- Have you tried other EditText manipulations: YES I tried setText and that also failed with similar rates

Anyone have ideas?